# Question about maximal ideals of an algebra.

Tags: representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra. Let $\text{rad}A$ be the radical of $A$. That is the intersection of all maximal right ideals of $A$. Suppose that $A/\text{rad}A$ is isomorphic to $K$. How can we show that $\text{rad}A$ is the unique proper maximal right ideal of $A$?

It is said that we can use the result: Let I be a two-side ideal nilpotent ideal of A. If $A/I$ is isomorphic to $K\times \cdots \times K$ (some copies of K), then $I=\text{rad}A$. But I don't konw how to use this result since here I is a two-side ideal but we need maximal ideal. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $K$ is a field.  That $\mathrm{rad} A$ is maximal as a right ideal is immediate from the fact that the quotient $A/\mathrm{rad} A \simeq K$ has dimension $1$ so there can be no intermediate ideals between $\mathrm{rad} A$ and $A$.

That $\mathrm{rad} \ A$ is the *unique* maximal ideal now follows from the fact that it is maximal but also contained in all other maximal right ideals.